# How to open a dialog without a button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

If the FTP file download fails, a notification window is displayed. Success or failure is returned as a bool variable. (return false if failure). The Android standard `showDialog` was successful.

```
if(context.read<ScoreImageProvider>().bDownloadRes == false){
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _ftpErrorAlert(context);
      });
    }
```

However, the iOS standard `showCupertinoDialog` is not executed. My `dialog function` is like this.

```
_ftpErrorAlert(BuildContext context){
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    Platform.isAndroid ?
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
          title: _ftpErrorTitle(size),
          content: _ftpErrorContent(size),
          actions: <Widget>[_ftpErrorOkButton(size)],
        )
    ) :
    showCupertinoDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (_) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
          title: _ftpErrorTitle(size),
          content: _ftpErrorContent(size),
          actions: <Widget>[_ftpErrorOkButton(size)],
        )
    );
  }
```

Do you know how to callback `showCupertinoDialog` without a button?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***Solved***

Checked using a timer. If you `cancel()` the timer variable when `dispose` is called, it works normally.

```
chkTime = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if(nChkCount == false 20) {
        Timer.run(() {
          showAlert(context);
          timer.cancel();
        });
      }
      nChkCount++;
    });

void showAlert(BuildContext context){
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    Platform.isAndroid ?
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
            title: _title(),
            content: _content(),
            actions: [_action()],
          )
        ) :
        showCupertinoDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (_) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: _title(),
            content: _content(),
            actions: [_action()],
          )
    );
  }

void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    chkTime!.cancel();
    chkTime = null;
    super.dispose();
  }
```